# How can I restart the cinnamon panel keyboard layout selector?

Tags: keyboard-layout, cinnamon, panel, language

Somehow, the language indicator / keyboard layout switcher on my cinnamon panel has disappeared. This happens to me once in a while, and I'm used to having to logout and start a new session. But - can I restart it somehow?

I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera (~= Debian Bullseye without systemd), with two input languages, English and Hebrew. Will provide additional information as requested...

Comment: To reset Cinnamon, press Alt+F2, then press "r" and "ENTER".

Comment: @ajgringo619: That worked, but didn't help. That is, Cinnamon restarted, but the keyboard layout selector is not back.

Comment: Every once in a blue moon, I have to remove then re-add one of my applets (usually the timer). This may be your only option, outside of a full restart.

Comment: @ajgringo619: The keyboard layout selector cannot be removed as an applet, it's locked.

Comment: I can add/remove it on **EndeavourOS** (Arch-based) without a problem. Can't tell you why yours doesn't allow it.

Comment: @ajgringo619: Interesting... do you use multiple keyboard layouts?

Comment: No, no reason at this time.

Comment: @ajgringo619: So maybe that's why you can remove it. I suppose I could try dropping a layout and adding it back in.